# GCP No Organization migration fails for single project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration

I have successfully moved 3 or 4 projects under our "No Organization" Organization to our "domain" organization using one account. The permissions of this account are:

```
Kubernetes Engine Admin
Logging Admin
Owner
Organization Administrator
Project IAM Admin
Project Mover
Storage Admin
Storage Object Admin
```

There is however a single project for which the "Migrate" option is grayed out. I have confirmed I am an owner, have mover permissions, and project create permissions within the target "domain" organization.

Working with the gcloud CLI I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.projects.move) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Moving a project to another organization is currently unsupported.
    field: Project.parent
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
  reason: PROJECT_UPDATE_CROSS_ORG_MOVE
```

From this command:

```
gcloud beta projects move projectID --organization=XXXXXXXXX
```

How can I force this migration or diagnose the blocking issue?

Comment: 1/2): The error message appears to be about an ORG to ORG move, double-check if the project is actually part of another organization.

Comment: 2/2): To move a project into an organization now requires an additional permission `resourcemanager.projects.setIAMPolicy`. This permission is typically granted via the `Owner` role which you have but double-check. Two other permissions are required `resourcemanager.projects.create` and `resourcemanager.projects.update` which you probably already have in order to move projects previously. Use the CLI command `gcloud iam roles describe ROLE_ID` to describe the permissions in a role.

Comment: One additional comment. You have the `Owner` role. This means that you have the other permissions granted by the roles in your list. Double-check that you understand Google Cloud IAM correctly and are using least privilege. The member ID that has the `Owner` role should be locked away and not used during normal work, except for tasks like this one (project migration).

Comment: THe projects are confirmed in No Organization, thank you for the suggestion. As far as the duplicative permissions we are rolling them back but wanted to try and add explicit calls as much as possible to debug this.

Comment: Do you have `Project Creator` at the Organization level?

Comment: Have you checked documentation [Migrating projects with no organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing#migrating_projects_with_no_organization)? Do you have all re required permissions?

Comment: @M.Goodman Where you able to resolve this? I'm hitting the same issue myself. I'm owner of both project and org, the project is under "no organization" and I get the same error you did.

Comment: @JonatanB We ended up having to contact our organizational rep who modified this. I wish I could be of more help to resolving this quickly.